# How do you pass a variable between screens in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Here is my code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager


build = f"""
WindowManager:
    ScreenOne:

<ScreenOne>:
    name: 'one'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            text: 'Load Screen Two'
            on_release:
                app.root.load_screen_two('Screen Two')
                app.root.current = 'two'


<ScreenTwo>:
    name: 'two'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size: root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: root.text
"""


class ScreenOne(Screen):
    pass


class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    def __init__(self, text, **kw):
        super().__init__(**kw)
        self.text = text


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def load_screen_two(self, text):
        self.add_widget(ScreenTwo(text))


class Application(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(build)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Application().run()
```

I am attempting to instantiate a new screen by the click of a button in another screen.  That in and of itself works flawlessly!  The other thing I'm trying to do is pass a variable to that screen for use with methods I will be writing later on.  In this sample here I am simply passing a string.  Whenever I attempt to run this, after clicking the button in screen one, I get the following error: `AttributeError: 'ScreenTwo' object has no attribute 'text'`

How can I get around this and successfully pass a variable between screens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `StringProperty` for the attribute `text` and pass it to `ScreenTwo` as a kwarg.

```py
class ScreenTwo(Screen):
    text = StringProperty("")


class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    def load_screen_two(self, text):
        self.add_widget(ScreenTwo(text = text))
```

However, is the following a typing error or it is actually there in the original code ? If the latter is the case here, the indentations should be consistent.

```py
        Button:
            text: 'Load Screen Two'
            on_release:
                on_press: app.root.load_screen_two('Screen Two')
                on_release: Factory.NewGame().open()
                app.root.current = 'two'
```

Comment: Worked perfect!  But I did still have to keep the init method.  Thank you!

That bit was definitely a typo, I've edited my question to fix it.  thank you!